# Why aren't bits 11 and 12 of a segment descriptor grouped together?

Tags: x86, x86-64, hardware, intel, gdt

A question on definition: the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual, Vol 3A, summarises segment descriptor fields in section 5.2. How come the "type" field is defined as bits 8 through 11, and does not include bit 12, which is simply stated to be the "descriptor type flag"? Considering that bits 11 and 12 are used together to determine whether a segment is a code, data, or system segment, isn't it more logical to group them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because structure of TYPE field (bits 8-11) is very different when S field (bit 12) is 0 or 1.

When this field is 1, we have following table:

```
   11 10 9 8
0   0  0 0 0 Data Read-Only
1   0  0 0 1 Data Read-Only, accessed
2   0  0 1 0 Data Read/Write
3   0  0 1 1 Data Read/Write, accessed
4   0  1 0 0 Data Read-Only, expand-down
5   0  1 0 1 Data Read-Only, expand-down, accessed
6   0  1 1 0 Data Read/Write, expand-down
7   0  1 1 1 Data Read/Write, expand-down, accessed
8   1  0 0 0 Code Execute-Only
9   1  0 0 1 Code Execute-Only, accessed
10  1  0 1 0 Code Execute/Read
11  1  0 1 1 Code Execute/Read, accessed
12  1  1 0 0 Code Execute-Only, conforming
13  1  1 0 1 Code Execute-Only, conforming, accessed
14  1  1 1 0 Code Execute/Read, conforming
15  1  1 1 1 Code Execute/Read, conforming, accessed
```

But when this field is 0, table is very different:

```
   11 10 9 8 32-Bit Mode            IA-32e Mode
0   0  0 0 0 Reserved               Upper 8 bytes of an 16-byte descriptor
1   0  0 0 1 16-bit TSS (Available) Reserved
2   0  0 1 0 LDT                    LDT
3   0  0 1 1 16-bit TSS (Busy)      Reserved
4   0  1 0 0 16-bit Call Gate       Reserved
5   0  1 0 1 Task Gate              Reserved
6   0  1 1 0 16-bit Interrupt Gate  Reserved
7   0  1 1 1 16-bit Trap Gate       Reserved
8   1  0 0 0 Reserved               Reserved
9   1  0 0 1 32-bit TSS (Available) 64-bit TSS (Available)
10  1  0 1 0 Reserved               Reserved
11  1  0 1 1 32-bit TSS (Busy)      64-bit TSS (Busy)
12  1  1 0 0 32-bit Call Gate       64-bit Call Gate
13  1  1 0 1 Reserved               Reserved
14  1  1 1 0 32-bit Interrupt Gate  64-bit Interrupt Gate
15  1  1 1 1 32-bit Trap Gate       64-bit Trap Gate
```

So, of course you can consider 12th bit as part of descriptor type, but it is easier to think about them as two separate properties.

So for code/data segments you're using next 4 bits as bit mask (ie each bit determines whether some "feature" is on or off, for example 11th bit 0 means data), but for system segments you're considering it as single value 0-15, where each bit does not have particular meaning